# How to rewrite all subdomains except one

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd, mod-rewrite

Right now my rewrite rule forwards all subdomains except `chat.auricle.fm` to the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.auricle\.fm [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://auricle.fm/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I change it so that it forwards all subdomains except for `chat.auricle.fm`?

Answer (score 3):

I've almost never done any apache configuration, but it took me 2 minutes to find this:

> By default successive RewriteCond directives are linked by a logical AND. There is an optional modifier, [OR], that allows you to chain the next RewriteCond with a logical OR.

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.auricle\.fm [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=chat.auricle.fm [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://auricle.fm/$1 [L,R=301]
```